# Google One Tap with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-one-tap

I use following code :

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        window.displayGSI = function () {
            google.accounts.id.initialize({
                client_id: '[MY_CLIENT_iD]',
                auto_select: true
            });
            google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
                console.log(notification)
            });
        };

        window.displayGSI();
    });
</script>
```

In private navigation or not, this works fine with firefox but not with chrome.

With firefox, `console.log` returns `{ g: "display", h: true }`

With chrome, `console.log` returns `{g: 'display', h: false, j: 'opt_out_or_no_session'}`

Do you have any idea please ?

Thanks for your help.